# Pandas and Jupyter not found after upgrading to Catalina

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, macos-catalina

I just updated my macOS to Catalina and I can't run python or open a jupyter notebook from terminal anymore. As an example, I get error message "ImportError: No module named pandas" when running my python code, and I get

> zsh: command not found: jupyter

when running

```
jupyter notebook
```

This issue has brought me to anaconda (I would love someone to explain me why. Does python need anaconda to be ran?). I have tried several suggestions from https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10998, e.g. I have tried copying folder "anaconda3" from "Relocated items" folder to "Users//", then

```
export PATH=''/Users/<username>/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

but I get either

> dquote>

or

> zsh: /Users//Applications/anaconda3/bin/conda: bad interpreter: /anaconda3/bin/python: no such file or directory

I then tried to reinstall Anaconda using the graphic installer (from https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#macos) following advice from someone from the anaconda team (https://www.anaconda.com/how-to-restore-anaconda-after-macos-catalina-update/) (I changed installation location to a folder I created in /Users//) but I still get the same error messages when running python3 or jupyter notebook.

How can successfully run python and jupyter notebook with macOS Catalina?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering to my own question in case it can help others ;)

I found my answer here: https://medium.com/@singhaniatanay18/mac-os-catalina-update-zsh-instead-of-bash-d688f68f70b8

(see comments as well)

Comment: Could you elaborate on the solution that worked for you?

Comment: One thing is to run "jupyter" in your terminal instead of "jupyter notebook". Does it make it for you?

Comment: You should elaborate your answer in order to make it independent of external sources. If someday the post disappears, your answer becomes useless.

Answer (score 5):

After installed macOS Catalina, we can switch the terminal from bash to zsh. There are many advantages from using zsh instead of bash, but One of the issues with zsh is some of the frameworks (jupyter notebook,conda) are not supported directly. Once I typed jupyter notebook in terminal to run it. It displayed “zsh: no such file or directory”.

The solver is simple but very difficult to find online.
If jupyter was already installed before the update and stopped working after zsh, you should be able to fix it by:
1.open zshrc in terminal by typing: open .zshrc or $open .zschrc
2. add the following line at the end of the file:
source ~/.bash_profile
It will ask zsh to use all the information from bash like the path of jupyter.

Hope it can help you out!

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS BigSur:

1. Uninstall Anaconda:`rm -f Anaconda-Navigator.app`
2. re-install `pip3 install jupyterlab`

Answer (score 0):

I just updated to Catalina, two days before Big Sur release.. oh well.
Catalina came with changes to security and bash, that will remain for future releases. So Catalina moves your anaconda3 folder to `/Users/Shared/Previously Relocated Items/Security/anaconda3` I tried to move it back to home directory, but that didn't work. So I deleted it, and reinstalled Anaconda using the command line installer **Not** the GUI installer, and it worked for me. You can follow instructions [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/mac-os/) and use `/Users/me/anaconda3` folder as recommended [here](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/how-to-restore-anaconda-after-macos-catalina-update).

Here are the commands that worked for me,

1. `shasum -a 256 /Users/username/anaconda3` . Although not sure it did anything
2. `bash ~/Downloads/Anaconda3-2020.02-MacOSX-x86_64.sh` or whatever the name of the command line installer from Conda in your Download folder, or wherever else you downloaded it.
   Use `sudo` in front of the command if permission was denied, then enter your log in password for your Mac
3. `source /Users/username/anaconda3/bin/activate conda init zsh`
4. `sudo conda init zsh` then enter your Mac's password.
   You should be all set now, and all commands like `ipython`, `conda info`, `jupyter notebook`, `pyspark` will all work.
   The last command will make step3 command persist i.e. initialize conda base environment, such that you can run `conda`, `ipython`, `jupyter notebook` the next time you use terminal.

Answer (score -1):

Install the Jupyter using Homebrew in zsh shell
If you don't Python install 3.3or higher.

Open terminal

Using Homewbrew install jupyter

`brew install jupyter`

Now, you start a notebook

`jupyter notebook`